# Testing Contemporaneous Correlation

Tags: regression, time-series, correlation, vector-autoregression

Suppose I have the following time series:

```
      Date       Return     Index
1   Jan 1986    0.0158573   101.5
2   Feb 1986    0.0758885   103.6
3   Mar 1986    0.0808990   102.0
4   Apr 1986    -0.0049736  99.3
5   May 1986    -0.0347486  100.0
6   Jun 1986    0.0293237   97.0
7   Jul 1986    -0.0555825  99.5
8   Aug 1986    0.0661703   101.0
9   Sep 1986    -0.0634481  102.3
10  Oct 1986    0.0490423   104.4
11  Nov 1986    0.0028185   107.4
12  Dec 1986    0.0258447   107.0
13  Jan 1987    0.0770101   107.9
14  Feb 1987    0.0945087   113.3
15  Mar 1987    0.0092967   114.0
```

I am interested in testing whether the contemporaneous correlation is different from zero. I am trying to reproduce the same results of a paper and could not find my way with the contemporaneous correlation.

Comment: Correlation between the return and the index?

Comment: yes it is but taking time into account @Glen_b

Comment: Taking time into account in some way beyond the pairing of contemporaneous points? Or is that pairing all you mean? Just taking the ordinary correlation I get 0.3579. What did they have in the paper?

Comment: It may be that pairing what they mean in the paper. They worked that correlation out to be 0.29 with t-stat = 4.75. http://www.dnb.nl/binaries/ms2002-11_tcm46-147323.pdf this is the link of the paper. I am interested to get the same results of the last line of table 1. You might also need a look at the data. You will find a file called ukdata.csv at https://github.com/ahmedfsalhin/1stpaper